# Debugging an office-addin

Tags: macos, debugging, office365, office-js, office-addins

It looks like debugging an office add-in created with yo office on a mac running vscode looks like not really working fine.

I can run the add-in, bit debugging does not work either the web, nor the desktop version on a Mac.

has anyone managed to get it working?

Using the web version, results in that the https://127.0.0.1:3000/manifest.xml cannot be loaded.
Using the desktop version results in an error message, telling:

```
[vscode-debugger-extension-for-office-addins] Error processing "attach": Microsoft Office Add-in Debugger is only supported on Windows 10 version 1903 (build 10.0.18362) and greater.
```

trying successfully debugging an office add-in on a MacOS Macbook pro

Answer (score 3):

If you have add-in that shows UI in a task pane or in a content add-in, you can debug an Office Add-in using `Safari Web Inspector`. See [Debug Office Add-ins on a Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac) for more information.